# Cannot taint null_resource

Tags: terraform

I got terraform 0.11.11.
The graph show that the resource in speaking is in root module

```
$ terraform graph
digraph {
        compound = "true"
        newrank = "true"
        subgraph "root" {
                "[root] data.template_file.default" [label = "data.template_file.default", shape = "box"]
                "[root] data.template_file.etcd" [label = 
...
                "[root] null_resource.service_resolv_conf" [label = "null_resource.service_resolv_conf", shape = "box"]
...
```

But the trying to taint it says it is not:

```
$ terraform taint null_resource.service_resolv_conf
The resource null_resource.service_resolv_conf couldn't be found in the module root.
```

#### updates

```
$ terraform state list|grep resolv_conf 
null_resource.service_resolv_conf[0] 
null_resource.service_resolv_conf[1]
```

then i tried:

```
$ terraform taint null_resource.service_resolv_conf[0] 

The resource null_resource.service_resolv_conf[0] couldn't be found in the module root.
```

and

```
$ terraform taint null_resource.service_resolv_conf 
The resource null_resource.service_resolv_conf couldn't be found in the module root.
```

Comment: If the code is in a module try' terraform taint -module=name null_resource.name

Comment: @victorm This ^ is the correct answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I found out the solution

It appears, then when there are more hosts in connection based on list (used 'count')

```
resource "null_resource" "provision_docker_registry" {
  count      = "${length(local.service_vms_names)}"
  depends_on = ["null_resource.service_resolv_conf"]

  connection {
    user        = "cloud-user"
    private_key = "${file("${path.module}/../ssh/${var.os_keypair}.pem")}"
    host        = "${element(local.service_fip, count.index)}"
  }
```

You taint the resource by specifying index after dot, i.e.

```
$ terraform taint null_resource.provision_docker_registry.0
The resource null_resource.provision_docker_registry.0 in the module root has been marked as tainted!
```

Voila!

I could have not found that in documentation. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

`terraform graph` gives your the whole picture about the resources and their relationship.

But it is not a good command for troubleshooting and understand how the resources are named in terraform `*.tfstate` file.

I would recommend to run with `terraform state list`, then you can easily know how to taint one of the resources in list.

```
terraform state list
terraform taint <copy resource directly from above list>
```

Comment: ok, i tried, but still it says it is not in root module, despite, it is...
`$ terraform state list|grep resolv_conf
null_resource.service_resolv_conf[0]
null_resource.service_resolv_conf[1]`
then i tried:
`$ terraform taint null_resource.service_resolv_conf[0]
The resource null_resource.service_resolv_conf[0] couldn't be found in the module root.` and `$ terraform taint null_resource.service_resolv_conf
The resource null_resource.service_resolv_conf couldn't be found in the module root.`
The same for both cases;

Comment: I noticed that if I don't have 'count' in resource then it works.

Answer (score 1):

For whoever who comes into this thread looking for terraform taint/untaint `null_resource` where terraform errors out with `The resource […] couldn't be found in the module root` here's the correct and working answer posted by @victor-m at [Cannot taint null_resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55029041/cannot-taint-null-resource#comment96812193_55029041)

```
terraform taint -module=name null_resource.name
```

Same for `untaint` command.